# Selecting text terms based on BERT attention scores

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

Given a sequence pair (query, text) as input to a transformer model such as [BERTModel](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/bert#transformers.BertModel), how do we select the n-grams (unigrams and bigrams) in the text with the highest attention score concerning the query?

```py
query = "machine learning"
text = """
         Supervised learning is the machine learning task of learning a function that
         maps an input to an output based on example input-output pairs. It infers a
         function from labeled training data consisting of a set of training examples.
         In supervised learning, each example is a pair consisting of an input object
         (typically a vector) and a desired output value (also called the supervisory signal).
         A supervised learning algorithm analyzes the training data and produces an inferred function,
         which can be used for mapping new examples.
      """
```

**possible answer**: machine learning, supervised learning, function, labeled training.

For a quick start, we could extract the attention scores using the following code snippet:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, BertModel
import torch
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
model = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", output_attentions=True)

query = "machine learning"
text = """
         Supervised learning is the machine learning task of learning a function that
         maps an input to an output based on example input-output pairs. It infers a
         function from labeled training data consisting of a set of training examples.
         In supervised learning, each example is a pair consisting of an input object
         (typically a vector) and a desired output value (also called the supervisory signal).
         A supervised learning algorithm analyzes the training data and produces an inferred function,
         which can be used for mapping new examples.
      """
# tokenized query and text as a sentece pair
input = tokenizer(text=query, text_pair=text, max_length=128,
                                  padding="max_length", truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
# {'input_ids': tensor([[  101,  3698,  4083,   102, 13588,  4083,  2003,  1996,  3698,  4083,
#           4708,  1997,  4083,  1037,  3853,  2008,  7341,  2019,  7953,  2000,
#           2019,  6434,  2241,  2006,  2742,  7953,  1011,  6434,  7689,  1012,
#           2009,  1999, 24396,  1037,  3853,  2013, 12599,  2731,  2951,  5398,
#           1997,  1037,  2275,  1997,  2731,  4973,  1012,  1999, 13588,  4083,
#           1010,  2169,  2742,  2003,  1037,  3940,  5398,  1997,  2019,  7953,
#           4874,  1006,  4050,  1037,  9207,  1007,  1998,  1037,  9059,  6434,
#           3643,  1006,  2036,  2170,  1996, 26653,  4742,  1007,  1012,  1037,
#          13588,  4083,  9896, 17908,  2015,  1996,  2731,  2951,  1998,  7137,
#           2019,  1999,  7512,  5596,  3853,  1010,  2029,  2064,  2022,  2109,
#           2005, 12375,  2047,  4973,  1012,   102,     0,     0,     0,     0,
#              0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
#              0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0]]), 'token_type_ids': tensor([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
#          1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
#          1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
#          1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
#          1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
#          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]), 'attention_mask': tensor([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
#          1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
#          1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
#          1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
#          1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
#          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])}

# Make predictions with the model
outputs = model(**input)

# Extract attention scores with shape (batch_size, num_heads, sequence_length, sequence_length)
attention_scores = outputs['attentions']
```

Comment: Bert has multiple layers and multiple attention heads in each layer. Please specify what kind of aggregation are you looking for, or otherwise which layer & head would you like to take the attention scores from. I suggest this as a good place to start https://github.com/jessevig/bertviz

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about what exactly you mean by `highest attention score concerning the query?`. The bert model has 12 layers, with 12 attention heads per layer. This means `outputs['attentions']` contains 12 attention tensors of size `(bs, 12, sl, sl)`.

You could start with something like this

```py
# mask tokens based on query/response, ignoring padding
query_mask = (input['attention_mask']==1) * (input['token_type_ids']==0)
text_mask = (input['attention_mask']==1) * (input['token_type_ids']==1)

# grab attention from final layer of the model
attention = outputs.attentions[-1]

# this subsets the attention matrix to size `(12, n_query_tokens, n_response_tokens)`
# this has to be a for loop because the values of `n_query_tokens` and `n_response_tokens` will be different for different batch items
bs = attention.shape[0]
extracted_attentions = []
for i in range(bs):
    q_mask = query_mask[i]
    t_mask = text_mask[i]

    masked_attention = attention[i, :, q_mask, :][:, :, t_mask]

    extracted_attentions.append(masked_attention)

# grab attention submatrix for first batch item, as an example
extracted_attention = extracted_attentions[0]

# average over number of heads and query tokens
mean_attentions = torch.mean(extracted_attention, (0,1))

# get topk mean attention values
k = 10
topk_attention_values, topk_idxs = mean_attentions.topk(k)

# get response tokens for first batch item
response_token_ids = input['input_ids'][0][text_mask[0]]

# grab topk tokens by attention score
topk_tokens = response_token_ids[topk_idxs]

# decode back to tokens
tokenizer.decode(topk_tokens)
```

This could be considered a form of "highest attention score". You will notice the results change based on what attention layer we use.

If you use the final layer, the top 10 tokens are `'.... [SEP] ) ), learning is'`. If you use the first layer, you get `'supervised learning the machine [SEP] learning task learning. a'`

You should think about what the attention scores are actually doing (in this case, aiding the problem of masked token filling), what problem you are trying to solve, and why you think the answer to your problem can be found within the attention weights.